# Catch received packets before Windows processes them

Tags: python, windows, packet, python-sockets

I'm trying to catch packets that I receive on Windows 10, before Windows could process them, and modify them.

How actually I can do it?

Some thoughts -

1. Create windows network adapter, that will be connected like:
   ( my real network adapter - new adapter - internet )
2. Get response to some opened socket, receive there packet, decrypt it, and then somehow make google chrome process it.

to catch packets on this new adapter, modify them, and then send them to real network adapter.

**A little bit more info:**

Im creating a vpn server ( proxy + encrypted payload )

So, on client , i catch all my trafic "on a fly" modifying them ( encrypt payload ), send it to server, server decrypts packet, and sends it to internet, receives response, encrypts it, and sends it back.
The client receives - (for example simple http html response) with encrypted payload. And before windows network stack will receive this packet to process it, i need to decrypt it.

Comment: Look at wireshark's sources or any other network packet sniffer's and similar applications. BTW: It may be easier to just put a proxy in between the outside and the actual app, which could be done on the TCP level without anything as low-level as that. It's impossible to tell whether that's feasible though, due to the little info you provide concerning your actual goal.

Comment: Hi @Ulrich Eckhardt, thanks for response, actually i don`t know if some kind of packet sniffer will be able to do what i want, cause it only sniffs packets, but not intercepts them from getting to windows network stack before packet will be decrypted, i added some more info at "a little bit more info" and 1 more "thoughts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, found out the answer.

To achieve, what i was trying to do you can use Pydivert - https://pypi.org/project/pydivert/
Using it, you can stop inbound and outbound packets and modify them, before they will be processed by Windows network stack.